# Get current anchor href on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, anchor, this

I have a list of links, that I've made a 'popup' div for, on hover. The links all point to a query like `?page=link1`. I am trying to get the value after the query, so `link1` and put it in the div's html. Right now with .match in there nothing will happen. If i use just .attr('href') then I get an 'undefined' response.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[Heres a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9X7ee/2/)

And heres the code I have right now. Any kind of help to get me in the right direction would be great. I know I'm close, I just don't have THAT good of an understanding with jquery yet.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;
    $('#pops').hover(function(a) {
        var file = $(this).attr("href").match(/page=([0-9]+)/)[1];
        $('#pop-up').html('file name is ' + file);
        $('#pop-up').show();
        return false
        a.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#pops').mousemove(function(b) {
        $("#pop-up").css('top', b.pageY + moveDown).css('left', b.pageX + moveLeft);
        return false
        b.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

**UPDATE:** my links were described incorrectly. queries actually contain numbers, letters, and decimals.

```
<div id="pops">
 <a href="content.asp?page=ns2.6">link 1</a><br>
 <a href="content.asp?page=ns3.8">link 2</a><br>
 <a href="content.asp?page=jp1.0">link 3</a><br>
 <a href="content.asp?page=jp2.1">link 4</a><br>
</div>
<div id="pop-up"></div>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer and example to reflect your link updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hover function should be:

```
$('#pops a').hover(function(e) {
    var file = $(this).attr("href").match(/page=(.*)/)[1];
    $('#pop-up').html('file name is ' + file);
    $('#pop-up').show();
    return false
    a.preventDefault();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fSRVy/3/)**

Note that the selector was wrong (should be `$('#pops a')`) and the regex was also incorrect (should be `/page=(.*)/`).

Comment: thank youre right about both. how could i change the regex to get all characters after just `page=` though?

Comment: @xxstevenxo - My update should do that. For example, if the links is `page=ns2.6` the above will grab `ns2.6`.

Comment: excellent! thank you very much :D! One more thing, sorry. the occasional link has a letter at the end of so sometimes there might be `ns2.6b` and the regex seems to only pick it up to the last number. Do I need to add something else to have it show the letter at the end of some of those links? Thank you again for you quick replies before.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector and regex is wrong, you need to select an `<a>` to get its `href` and you forgot the `link` in the regex.

```
        $('#pops a').hover(function(a) {
            var file = $(this).attr("href").match(/page=(link[0-9]+)/)[1];
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/9X7ee/7/)

This regex matches all the samples given `/page=([a-z]{2}\d\.\d)/`

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/9X7ee/8/

Comment: yes thank you, I didn't even realize i wasn't looking at the anchors specifically without the #pops a. I should have been more exact in my OP also. My queries use decimals, numbers and letters, so they actually look like `page=ns2.6`. How can i change the regex to grab everything after the equals character? so i can get the file name in its entirety.

Comment: There are alot of regular expressions that can match that, what are the specific criteria for the names?

Answer (score 1):

if your going to use 'this' then you need to target the 'a' element therefore :

```
$('#pops').hover(function(a) {
```

should be :

```
$('#pops a').hover(function(a) {
```

You could get the file name by using the JavaScript split method and selecting the second value of the array like this :

```
var fileName = file.split("=")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there are a few issues with your code :

1 - You want the hover to be associated to the anchors themselves not their container. 
i.e  `$('#pops a').hover(function(a) { ... });`

When you use $(this).attr("href")... `this` makes reference to the #pops container but you want it to reference the actual anchor.

2 - you were matching the wrong regex.

The below code works tested in your fiddle.

Hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var moveLeft = 20;
        var moveDown = 10;

        $('#pops a').hover(function(a) {
        var file = $(this).attr("href").match(/link\d/i);

        $('#pop-up').html('file name is ' + file);
        $('#pop-up').show();

        return false
        a.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#pops').mousemove(function(b) {
        $("#pop-up").css('top', b.pageY + moveDown).css('left', b.pageX + moveLeft);

        return false
        b.preventDefault();
        });    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex should be `/page=link([0-9]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

if only number in page in href attr occurs, simply

```
var file = $(this).attr("href").match(/([0-9]+)/);
```